# wp_get_current_user not in role

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following:

```
<?php $roles = array('silver_user','gold_user');
$user = wp_get_current_user();
foreach ($roles as $role){
if ( !in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles ) ) {
 echo '<i style="color:red;font-size:12px;">(CURRENT)</i>';
}
} ?>
```

Which should check if the current user does not have a silver_user or gold_user role. However regardless of whether or not I remove the !in_array marker it still shows the CURRENT text. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Whats the output of this? echo '<pre>'; print_r($user->roles);exit;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like below

```
<?php 
    $roles = array('silver_user','gold_user');
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( !in_array( $user->roles, $roles  ) ) {
        echo '<i style="color:red;font-size:12px;">(CURRENT)</i>';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess $user has role that is silver_user or gold_user. So when you use loop, it will always show CURRENT whether or not !in_array.

Answer (score 0):

The function `wp_get_current_user()` should be called from `init` action. You may need to move all the code into a function calling from `init`.

Also you can use WP native function `current_user_can()` to check the role. Here is the example

```
add_action('init', 'is_eligible_user');
function is_eligible_user(){

    $roles = array('silver_user', 'gold_user', 'author', 'administrator');

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    foreach( $roles as $role ) {
        if ( current_user_can( $role ) ) {
            echo "user has privilege"; break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $roles = array('silver_user', 'gold_user');

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if(!empty($user->roles)){    

    foreach ($roles as $role) {

        if (in_array($role, (array) $user->roles)) {

            echo '<i style="color:red;font-size:12px;">(CURRENT)</i>';
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: OK this works - but the problem is if they are not silver or gold, it shows the CURRENT echo twice...

Comment: @PaulVI . Not in array changed to In array - check now

Comment: But the CURRENT echo is only to show if they are not a silver_user or gold_user. What you had before was correct, but it showed that echo twice - (CURRENT)(CURRENT)

Comment: @PaulVI Whats the output of this? echo '<pre>'; print_r($user->roles);exit;

Comment: Array ( [0] => employer [1] => silver_user ) So the user will always have the employer role and either silver_user or gold_user